# Do I install ZooKeeper on each machine?

Tags: php, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, php-zookeeper

I am planning to use ZooKeeper in my system. I have 6 machines I need to coordinate. Do I understand correctly that I install ZooKeeper on each of those machines?

Some examples show I can create several instances on the same server, different port. What would be the use case for several instances on the same machine?

I do not think it is related, but I use PHP and the [Keeper extension](https://github.com/andreiz/php-zookeeper/).

I currently have 3 web servers, one backend server (for batch processes), Two db servers, one Log and monitoring server. Each has Java + Tomcat installed. The main reason I plan to use ZooKeeper for is to manage locks on various resources my system uses. Like, Memory, certain tables, disk IO. All of my machines are Linux.

Comment: Could I trouble you to use ordinary paragraphing for your posts? Since most of your questions and answers are like this, they are liable to cause extra editing work. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer would you give an example to what you mean. This is not on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper must be installed on an odd number of machines. The number of machines will determine if you install ZooKeeper in standalone mode (for one machine) or in replicated mode (for three or five machines).

Can you provide more information about your installation, like:
      1. In which environment you want to install: windows/linux etc
      2. Make sure you have Java in your system because zookeeper uses Java

Regards.